# how to use data attribute of select options in jquery filter?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a dependent dropdown and can't use the value attribute. I found codepen does exactly what I want, other than using value. So I forked it and changed value to data-size, which doesn't work.

I've tried using `$(this).data("size")` and some variations but probably had syntax errors.

```
<option value="1">Fruit</option>


<option data-size="1">Fruit</option>
```

Codepen using value https://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/OjNYZb

Codepen using data-size https://codepen.io/twiddly/pen/VJZgxZ

The dropdowns in data-size codepen still work but 2nd one is no longer dependent on the 1st.

Edit: thanks to freedomn-m, I have a working solution, but it ends with the last option in the list being 'selected', so **how to make it the first option?**

```js
var $select1 = $('#select1'),
  $select2 = $('#select2'),
  $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  var size = $(this).find("option:selected").data("size");
  $select2.html($options.filter('[data-size="' + size + '"]'));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
    <option data-size="1">Fruit</option>
    <option data-size="2">Animal</option>
    <option data-size="3">Bird</option>
    <option data-size="4">Car</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
    <option data-size="1">Banana</option>
    <option data-size="1">Apple</option>
    <option data-size="1">Orange</option>
    <option data-size="2">Wolf</option>
    <option data-size="2">Fox</option>
    <option data-size="2">Bear</option>
    <option data-size="3">Eagle</option>
    <option data-size="3">Hawk</option>
    <option data-size="4">BWM
      <option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `data-` just adds an annotation, you'll need some js / updated js to get it to work.  (there might be some in the codepen, but it needs to be here, not in a 3rd party site)

Comment: Please add your "*[mcve]*" code to your question, don't just link to it (especially with a text link buried in a code block).

Comment: You weren't far off - if you update your question with the code, I (or anyone else) can give you an explanation: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdzPRd

Comment: I thought folks would appreciate a codepen link versus a bunch of embedded code.
My apologies.
Thank you freedomn-m for the solution.

Comment: codepen/fiddle is good if you have a lot of code that can't be cut down, but even then, the crux needs to be in the question.  The problem is that 3rd party sites may  be offline or go down completely.

Comment: *"it ends with the last option in the list being 'selected'"* - this is also how the first codepen works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in using `$(this).data("size")`, but it needs to be applied to the selected `<option>` and not to the `<select>`

```
var size = $(this).find("option:selected").data("size");
$select2.html($options.filter('[data-size="' + size + '"]'));
```

It's not clear why this selects the last one during the `.html(.filter()`, but you can select the first one using `.first()` (or `:first`), or clear it completely using `.val("")`

Updated snippet:

```js
var $select1 = $('#select1'),
    $select2 = $('#select2'),
    $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  var size = $(this).find("option:selected").data("size");
  $select2.html($options.filter('[data-size="' + size + '"]'));
  $select2.val($select2.find("option:first").val());
  //$select2.val("");
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
    <option data-size="1">Fruit</option>
    <option data-size="2">Animal</option>
    <option data-size="3">Bird</option>
    <option data-size="4">Car</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
    <option data-size="1">Banana</option>
    <option data-size="1">Apple</option>
    <option data-size="1">Orange</option>
    <option data-size="2">Wolf</option>
    <option data-size="2">Fox</option>
    <option data-size="2">Bear</option>
    <option data-size="3">Eagle</option>
    <option data-size="3">Hawk</option>
    <option data-size="4">BWM
      <option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, although there is probably a better method:

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1'),
$select2 = $( '#select2' ),
$options = $select2.children();

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
$select2.html($options.filter( function(index) {
    return ($select1.find(":selected").data("size") == $(this).data("size"));
}));

}).trigger( "change" );
```

Basically filters the options set where that data attribute equal the selected option data attribute value in the first select list.  Kind of wondering why you need to do that rather than using values though.

Basically what freedomn-m posted.  Sorry about that.  Did not see that.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the `data-XXX` attributes via `.data("XXX")`

```js
console.log($("#one").val());
console.log($("#two").data("size"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<option id="one" value="1">Fruit</option>
<option id="two" data-size="2">Fruit</option>
```

Comment: So, like OP stated they tried already? `$(this).data("size")`  General opinion is to not encourage low quality questions that rely on jsfiddle/codepen rather than adding the code to the question as they don't help future users.